# SplitChunks shared modules are loaded async

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks

I'm trying to figure out how to configure Webpack 4's SplitChunks plugin. If I allow it to put modules in a shared/common chunk, it seems those modules are loaded async.

entry.js:

```
require("expose-loader?$!jquery");
```

This is included in the page:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   // do something spectacular
});
</script>
```

Without SplitChunks, JQuery is inside `bundle.js` and is immediately available to the page. However, once I enable SplitChunks and JQuery gets moved into a separate chunk, the page triggers an error: `$ is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of splitchunks is correct, the only thing that is missing is "expose" `$` to be used everywhere.

Try ProvidePlugin: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery